# How can I update specific field in database by HibernateTemplate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, exception, sql-update

I want to update a specific field in the database `Persons` table by using HibernateTemplate. I am trying to do like this but this not working.

```
public void  updateDate(int Id,Date receivedDate) {
      Id = 10;
      receivedDate = 2012-11-12;
      String queryString = "update Persons set recievedDate=? where Id=? ";
      getHibernateTemplate().update(queryString, new Object[] { Id, receivedDate });
}
```

I am getting an exception "UnkownEntity" when I run this query. Can I do update of a specific field at all by using HibernateTemplate? Is there any other alternate to do specific field update?

Comment: would you please show use the code of Entity Person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` method in `getHibernateTemplate` does not allow hql query to execute. It only allows hibernate entity object.

See link [hibernate template update method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

In your case Hibernate tries to resolve `update Persons set recievedDate=? where Id=?` as an entity.

**Solution:**

```
Query q = s.createQuery("update Persons set recievedDate=:recievedDate where Id=:Id");
q.setString("recievedDate", "some date");
q.setString("Id", "54");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Hope its clear.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's perfectly working for me. You saved me lot of time.

Comment: _As a side note:_ actually you still **can** use [`bulkUpdate(String queryString)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) to execute a query expressed in **Hibernate's query language**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to list your classes in your session factory configuration.

Comment: I already did that.The above same person object is working for other queries.Is my query in question correct?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your entity named Person
in HQL you must use java class name, not db table name

Answer (score -2):

if HibernateTemplate is using, here is my solution.

```
// EntityName is the table to be updated

EntityName entity =  hibernateTemplate.find("from EntityName where id=?" , id);

//set the value which has to be updated

entity.setValue(yourNewValue);

hibernateTemplate.SaveOrUpdate(entity);  

// above updated the existing Entity table without duplicates
```